# Whether TCP performance will be improved if Google BBR enabled on client?

Tags: linux, networking, kernel, tcp

I have recompiled linux kernel and enabled google bbr on my VPS, TCP transfer speed has improved about 3 times as before. But, what will be happened if I enable this feature on my client PC. The TCP transfer speed will be improved more or not? Have anyone tried?

Comment: You need to tell us more about your "client PC" before anybody can answer.

Comment: As far as I understand BBR is for the "emitter" side. So you won't see any benefit for your downloads.

Comment: @fpmurphy1 client PC is a normal linux pc that without special.

Comment: @xenoid you are right. Looks like it's useless for most PC. But some upload heavy application, such as torrent, will run more effective.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a use case similar to large data transfers (> 100 GB) between data centers or office sites you will not likely see much impact. The Internet quite unpredictable in terms of RTTs and bandwidth available between end hosts and most people do not have enough bandwidth where such a congestion control algorithm would provide that much of a benefit compared to Cubic.